# Consulta com sql não retorna quando usa WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, select, where

Tenho uma consulta que deveria trazer o nome dos usuários que receberam uma mensagem enviada por um usuário:

```
SELECT msg.msg_content
      ,usr.user_name
  FROM message AS msg
 INNER JOIN usuarios AS usr
    ON msg.user_id_out = usr.user_ssid
 WHERE usr.user_email = "***"
```

No formato acima, ele não retorna nenhum resultado, porém ao remover o `Where`, ele exibe todas as mensagens com o nome de quem recebeu, eu estou com esta dúvida onde não estou conseguindo imaginar a saída, preciso exibir as mensagens e os nomes de quem recebeu, porém só de quem enviou, de quem recebeu eu consigo tirando o `where`, mas não somente de quem enviou

---

De tanto insistir acabei batendo a cabeça no problema, é só iniciar mais um `inner join`, não sei se é assim mesmo a melhor forma, mas funcionou, se alguém souber uma forma melhor, me ajuda ai, aceito recomendações, mas a principio, pus mais um `join`

```
SELECT msg.msg_content
      ,usr.user_name
  FROM message AS msg
 INNER JOIN usuarios AS usr
    ON msg.user_id_out = usr.user_ssid
 INNER JOIN usuarios AS usr_in
    ON usr_in.user_ssid = msg.user_id_in
 WHERE usr_in.user_email = "***"
```

Alguém pode validar se esta é a melhor forma?

Comment: Não da para ajudar muito, porque se sabe quais as tabelas que vc tem :/
Mas em teoria esse seu segundo join esta so a por mais lenta a query..

Comment: poderia me ajudar como faria para retornar então os nomes dos usuarios out de uma tabela relacionada a outra com usuarios in na mesma tabela, exemplificando, tabela usuario, tabela mensagem, usuario envia mensagem (out) usuario recebe mensagem (in) tabela mensagem recebe id out e in, select name out e in

Comment: troca o " por ', sua consulta está correta, provavelmente o where está filtrando os dados e não encontrado resultados, verifique espaços em brancos. existe email igual a '***' ?

Comment: na verdade, nem " ou ' retornaram valor algum antes de inserir o segundo inner join, eu ocultei o email da representação acima, com o segundo inner join ele funciona perfeitamente, porém não sei se é aconselhavel, aliás, como utilizo no php o PDO :email então não faz diferença o " ou ' pois não se utiliza